# What is that rubbery white substance in switching power supplies?

Tags: materials

There is often some rubbery white substance (looks kind of like some hot-glue) in switching power supplies.

[image: example image of power supply]

In this example it's on the right side between those electrolytic capacitors.

What is it; what is it called like? And what is it's purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of silicone goo

It's there to stop the tall parts from flapping around and breaking off.